# Lifetime of rvalue reference

Tags: c++

I think I have a problem with understanding rvalue references. What is really the lifetime and usage of such construction.

```
int&& value = 5;
```

If I understand correctly, 5 is rvalue object (I can't take address of it) and it's temporary - lifetime is end of current expression. Does assigning that to rvalue reference somehow prolong lifetime? If yes, what is the new lifetime of object?

Comment: Binding a reference to a temporary object causes the object to have its lifetime extended to match the reference's lifetime.

Answer (score 21):

> Does assigning that to rvalue reference somehow prolong lifetime?

Yes. [Rvalue references](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference) can be used to extend the lifetimes of temporary objects (note, `lvalue references` to `const` can extend the lifetimes of temporary objects too, but they are not modifiable through them). Thus:

```
// both will extend the lifetime of the temporary
int&& value = 5;      // modifiable
const int& value = 5; // non-modifiable
```

> If yes, what is the new lifetime of object?

The lifetime of the temporary is extended to match the lifetime of the reference. See [lifetime of a temporary.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference_initialization#Lifetime_of_a_temporary)