# pass rvalue to std::move and bind rvalue refence to it generate stack-use-after-scope error in ASAN

Tags: c++, stdmove

considering this code snippet

```
#include <iostream>
int foo() {
  int a;
  return a;
}
int main() {
  auto &&ret = std::move(foo());
  std::cout << ret;
}
```

compile with ASAN `g++ -fsanitize=address -fno-omit-frame-pointer -g -std=c++17 main.cpp -o main`, run `./main` shows error

```
==57382==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: stack-use-after-scope on address 0x00016b3cb480 at pc 0x000104a37e68 bp 0x00016b3cb450 sp 0x00016b3cb448
READ of size 4 at 0x00016b3cb480 thread T0
    #0 0x104a37e64 in main main.cpp:8
    #1 0x104a75084 in start+0x200 (dyld:arm64e+0x5084)
```

But if I remove reference after auto, this piece of code can compile and run without an error given by ASAN. What I don't understand is that if `std::move` returns a reference to the object it is given, then that object, which is a temporary created by `foo()` in this example, will be destroyed after `std::move` function call return, so whether it is bind to rvalue reference or assigned to a new value should be invalid, because that temporary is already destroyed after move operation, right? Then why ASAN doesn't give an error in second case.

---------------------update----------------

```
 #include <iostream>
    int foo() {
      int a = 1;
      return a;
    }
    int main() {
      auto &&ret = std::move(foo());
      std::cout << ret;
    }
```

if I don't compile with ASAN, this code will actually run without an error, it doesn't trigger segmentation fault or anything, and print 1 which is the same as `a` in `foo` funtion. and from the answers below I learned that the temporary is destroyed after `auto &&ret = std::move(foo());` right? Is this an undefined behavior?

Comment: This is **undefined behavior** as `a` is uninitialized. [Enable all warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57842756/why-should-i-always-enable-compiler-warnings).

Comment: `std::move` doesnt actually move.

Comment: `T&&` can bind to temporary and prolong the lifetime. but not the case when it's already reference. EDIT: I see, you're not talking about remove `std::move` but `auto&&` -> `auto`

Comment: Also, [std::move doesn't actually move anything](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27026280/12002570)

Comment: The temporary is not destroyed until the *full expression* is finished, ie at the `;`, after the reference is bound.

Comment: For built in types like `int`, you just copy the variable.

Comment: its a source of confusion to only describe how code should be modified rather than showing the modified code. I suppose you mean `auto ret = std::move(foo());`, right? Please clarify that in the quesiton

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number yes that's what I mean

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assigning a **prvalue** (such as an `int`) to an `auto&&` variable will enable [lifetime extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49371012/lifetime-of-rvalue-reference).  The temporary will exist as long as your variable exists.

Passing a prvalue to `std::move()` will convert the prvalue (`int`) to an **xvalue** (`int&&`).  Lifetime extension no longer applies, and the temporary is destroyed before reaching `std::cout << ret;`

This is why the presence of your `std::move` is triggering stack-use-after-scope.  The move is preventing lifetime extension.

**The lesson: you likely never want to pass a prvalue (a temporary) to `std::move`.**

Comment: OP is not asking about remove `std::move` (which I also take wrong at first)

Comment: Thanks, i understand it now, temporary is destroyed  at the end of full expression, and lifetime extension not applied for xvalue

Comment: but if I don't compile with ASAN, the code with "auto &&ret = std::move(foo());" can actually run without error, doesn't trigger segmentation fault or anything, and printed value is the same as a in foo funtion (i assigned a value to a). Is this an undefined behavior?

Comment: @codesavesworld Yes.  It is a dangling reference and UB.

Answer (score 6):

the temporary is only destroyed after the *full expression*. (after the initialization of `ret`)

```
// 1. the temporary is created and bind to std::move parameter
// 2. std::move return reference to the temporary
// 3. it's *value* copied to ret
// 4. temporary is destoryed, but it'd not effect the copy (`ret`)
auto ret = std::move(foo());
```

```
// 1. the temporary is created and bind to std::move parameter
// 2. std::move return reference to the temporary
// 3. the *reference* is set to `ret`
// 4. temporary is destoryed, `ret` now contains dangling reference
auto&& ret = std::move(foo());
```

Answer (score 3):

First things first, the program has **undefined behavior** as `a` is uninitialized and you're *copying* it as your function returns **by value**.
This applies to both of your cases. Note that even though in the first case a reference is bind, your function still return by value so there is a copy involved theoretically(according to the standard), which will use the uninitialized variable with indeterminate value.

Next, `std::move(foo())` is an xvalue expression and so the lifetime extension does not apply. The temporary will be destroyed at the end of the full expression.

Also refer to [Why should I always enable compiler warnings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57842756/why-should-i-always-enable-compiler-warnings).