# Flattening iterator for boost multi_array of linked lists

Tags: c++, boost

I have implemented a custom container type that stores integers within a `boost::multi_array<std::list<int>, 2>`. I want to be able to use a *single* range-based for loop to iterate through all `int` in this nested data structure (see code below for the desired loop construct).

To do so, I'm trying to adapt [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3623597/4188928). Here is the code from that solution plus a container definition and test code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <boost/multi_array.hpp>

template <typename OuterIterator>
class flattening_iterator
{
public:

    typedef OuterIterator                                outer_iterator;
    typedef typename OuterIterator::value_type::iterator inner_iterator;

    typedef std::forward_iterator_tag                iterator_category;
    typedef typename inner_iterator::value_type      value_type;
    typedef typename inner_iterator::difference_type difference_type;
    typedef typename inner_iterator::pointer         pointer;
    typedef typename inner_iterator::reference       reference;

    flattening_iterator() { }
    flattening_iterator(outer_iterator it) : outer_it_(it), outer_end_(it) { }
    flattening_iterator(outer_iterator it, outer_iterator end)
        : outer_it_(it),
          outer_end_(end)
    {
        if (outer_it_ == outer_end_) { return; }

        inner_it_ = outer_it_->begin();
        advance_past_empty_inner_containers();
    }

    reference operator*()  const { return *inner_it_;  }
    pointer   operator->() const { return &*inner_it_; }

    flattening_iterator& operator++()
    {
        ++inner_it_;
        if (inner_it_ == outer_it_->end())
            advance_past_empty_inner_containers();
        return *this;
    }

    flattening_iterator operator++(int)
    {
        flattening_iterator it(*this);
        ++*this;
        return it;
    }

    friend bool operator==(const flattening_iterator& a,
                           const flattening_iterator& b)
    {
        if (a.outer_it_ != b.outer_it_)
            return false;

        if (a.outer_it_ != a.outer_end_ &&
            b.outer_it_ != b.outer_end_ &&
            a.inner_it_ != b.inner_it_)
            return false;

        return true;
    }

    friend bool operator!=(const flattening_iterator& a,
                           const flattening_iterator& b)
    {
        return !(a == b);
    }

private:

    void advance_past_empty_inner_containers()
    {
        while (outer_it_ != outer_end_ && inner_it_ == outer_it_->end())
        {
            ++outer_it_;
            if (outer_it_ != outer_end_)
                inner_it_ = outer_it_->begin();
        }
    }

    outer_iterator outer_it_;
    outer_iterator outer_end_;
    inner_iterator inner_it_;
};

template <typename Iterator>
flattening_iterator<Iterator> flatten(Iterator it)
{
    return flattening_iterator<Iterator>(it, it);
}

template <typename Iterator>
flattening_iterator<Iterator> flatten(Iterator first, Iterator last)
{
    return flattening_iterator<Iterator>(first, last);
}

template <typename T, typename E>
class NestedContainer {
    T data;
    E extent;
    public:
        NestedContainer(E extent) : extent(extent) {
            // fill the container with sample data
            data.resize(extent);
            std::size_t i = 0;
            for ( auto &d: data ) {
                for ( std::size_t j = i; j < i+3; j++ ) {
                    d.push_back(i);
                }
                i += 3;
            }
        }
        auto begin() { return flatten(data.begin(), data.end()); }
        auto end() { return data.end(); }
};

int main()
{
    auto c1 = NestedContainer<std::vector<std::vector<int>>, std::size_t>(3); // works
    auto c2 = NestedContainer<std::vector<std::list<int>>, std::size_t>(3); // works
    // auto c3 = NestedContainer<boost::multi_array<std::list<int>, 2>, boost::multi_array_types::extent_gen::gen_type<2>::type>(boost::extents[2][2]); // does not compile

    auto c = c1;
    // loop
    for ( auto &val: c ) {
        std::cout << val << " ";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

By above code, the approach works for a vector of vectors and a vector of lists, but not for a multi_array of lists:

```
fiter.cpp: In instantiation of ‘NestedContainer<T, E>::NestedContainer(E) [with T = boost::multi_array<std::__cxx11::list<int>, 2>; E = boost::detail::multi_array::extent_gen<2>]’:
fiter.cpp:123:147:   required from here
fiter.cpp:108:13: error: cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type ‘boost::detail::multi_array::sub_array<std::__cxx11::list<int>, 1>&’ to an rvalue of type ‘boost::iterators::detail::iterator_facade_base<boost::detail::multi_array::array_iterator<std::__cxx11::list<int>, std::__cxx11::list<int>*, mpl_::size_t<2>, boost::detail::multi_array::sub_array<std::__cxx11::list<int>, 1>, boost::iterators::random_access_traversal_tag>, boost::multi_array<std::__cxx11::list<int>, 1, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::list<int> > >, boost::iterators::random_access_traversal_tag, boost::detail::multi_array::sub_array<std::__cxx11::list<int>, 1>, long int, false, false>::reference’ {aka ‘boost::detail::multi_array::sub_array<std::__cxx11::list<int>, 1>’}
  108 |             for ( auto &d: data ) {
      |             ^~~
fiter.cpp:110:23: error: ‘class boost::detail::multi_array::sub_array<std::__cxx11::list<int>, 1>’ has no member named ‘push_back’
  110 |                     d.push_back(i);
      |                     ~~^~~~~~~~~
```

It seems that the iterators returned by the `begin()` and `end()` member functions of `boost::multi_array` do not behave analogously as the ones from `vector`. Somehow they point to a `sub_array` instead of a `std::list<int>`, but I can't understand my underlying misconception from [the concise reference documentation of multi_array](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_83_0/libs/multi_array/doc/reference.html#MultiArray) and figuring it out from the source code of `multi_array` is currently beyond my proficiency.

Comment: I've assumed `push_back(i)` was supposed to be `push_back(j)` so you get `[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]` instead of `[0,0,0,3,3,3,6,6,6]` while `j` remained unused

Comment: Good assumption, that's how it should have been.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It seems that the iterators returned by the begin() and end() member functions of boost::multi_array do not behave analogously as the ones from vector. Somehow they point to a sub_array instead of a std::list

Yes. That's the reason it's called `multi_array`, not `array`. A multi-array is an abstraction that **behaves like** a container of sub-arrays (incidentally on top of some contiguous storage). At the lowest dimension *these* are themselves going to be containers of the element type.

To behave this way with minimal overhead (unlike your `vector<list>` and `vector<vector>`) the library uses Proxy Type: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Temporary_Proxy

Because the proxy is a temporary, you cannot bind a mutable reference with `auto&`. Instead, in generic code you often prefer to bind lvalue reference with `auto&&` which will extend the lifetime of the temporary: [Lifetime of rvalue reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49371012/lifetime-of-rvalue-reference/51413897#51413897)

```
 for (auto&& d : data)
```

However, it still won't work with your `push_back`, obviously.

### Rethink #1

Instead of assuming 80% of the `data` interface, and leaving a few nuts-and-bolts (like `extent`) fuzzy, make the entire `Data` type configurable:

```
template <typename Data> class NestedContainer {
    Data data;

  public:
    template <typename E> NestedContainer(E extent) : data(extent) {}
    auto begin() { return flatten(data.begin(), data.end()); }
    auto end()   { return data.end(); }
};
```

Now you can define storage to cater for your vector/list based approach:

```
#include <vector>
template <typename T, typename Row = std::vector<T>> //
struct VMatrix : std::vector<Row> {
    using Base = std::vector<Row>;
    using Base::operator=;
    VMatrix(VMatrix const&) = default;
    VMatrix(size_t extent = 0) : Base(extent, Row(extent, T{})) {
        for (int i = 0; auto&& row : *this)
            for (auto& el : row)
                el = i++;
    }
};
```

Just like you can define one for the multi_array appraoch:

```
#include <boost/multi_array.hpp>
template <typename T> //
struct MAMatrix : boost::multi_array<T, 2> {
    using Base = boost::multi_array<T, 2>;
    using Base::operator=;

    MAMatrix(MAMatrix const&) = default;
    MAMatrix(int extent = 0) : Base(boost::extents[extent][extent]) {
        for (int i = 0; auto&& row : *this)
            for (auto& el : row)
                el = i++;
    }
};
```

Which also just works (note the `auto&& row` loop variable!)

**[Live On Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4a473b061e25da7d)**

```
template <typename Data> class NestedContainer {
    Data data;

  public:
    template <typename E> NestedContainer(E extent) : data(extent) {}
    auto begin() { return flatten(data.begin(), data.end()); }
    auto end()   { return data.end(); }
};

#include <vector>
template <typename T, typename Row = std::vector<T>> //
struct VMatrix : std::vector<Row> {
    using Base = std::vector<Row>;
    using Base::operator=;
    VMatrix(VMatrix const&) = default;
    VMatrix(size_t extent = 0) : Base(extent, Row(extent, T{})) {
        for (int i = 0; auto&& row : *this)
            for (auto& el : row)
                el = i++;
    }
};

#include <boost/multi_array.hpp>
template <typename T> //
struct MAMatrix : boost::multi_array<T, 2> {
    using Base = boost::multi_array<T, 2>;
    using Base::operator=;

    MAMatrix(MAMatrix const&) = default;
    MAMatrix(int extent = 0) : Base(boost::extents[extent][extent]) {
        for (int i = 0; auto&& row : *this)
            for (auto& el : row)
                el = i++;
    }
};

#include <iostream>
#include <list>
int main() {
    auto c1 = NestedContainer<VMatrix<int>>(3);                 // works
    auto c2 = NestedContainer<VMatrix<int, std::list<int>>>(3); // works
    auto c3 = NestedContainer<MAMatrix<int>>(3);                // works

    for (auto sep = '\n'; auto& val : c1) std::cout << sep << val, sep = ' ';
    for (auto sep = '\n'; auto& val : c2) std::cout << sep << val, sep = ' ';
    for (auto sep = '\n'; auto& val : c3) std::cout << sep << val, sep = ' ';
}
```

Printing

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

### Rethink #2

You will correctly observe that `NestedContainer` doesn't add much value. In fact, it mostly has **cost** because it abuses `flattening_iterator` instead of leveraging the contiguous storage that `multi_array` already natively affords!

So, I'd lose the middle man and the cost overhead it introduced:

> ***Note** it also removed the dependency on `push_back` which not provided by all container types*

**[Live On Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dfa00498d314e7f6)**

```
template <typename T, typename Row = std::vector<T>> //
struct VMatrix : std::vector<Row> {
    using Base = std::vector<Row>;
    using Base::operator=;
    VMatrix(VMatrix const&) = default;
    VMatrix(size_t extent = 0) : Base(extent, Row(extent, T{})) {
        std::iota(begin(), end(), 0);
    }

    auto begin() { return flatten(Base::begin(), Base::end()); }
    auto end() { return flatten(Base::end(), Base::end()); }
};

#include <boost/multi_array.hpp>
template <typename T> //
struct MAMatrix : boost::multi_array<T, 2> {
    using Base = boost::multi_array<T, 2>;
    using Base::operator=;

    MAMatrix(MAMatrix const&) = default;
    MAMatrix(int n = 0) : Base(boost::extents[n][n]) { //
        std::iota(begin(), end(), 0);
    }

    auto begin() { return Base::origin(); }
    auto end() { return Base::origin() + Base::num_elements(); }
};

#include <fmt/ranges.h>
#include <list>
int main() {
    VMatrix<int>                 c1(3);
    VMatrix<int, std::list<int>> c2(3);
    MAMatrix<int>                c3(3);

    fmt::print("c1: {}\nc2: {}\nc3: {}\n", c1, c2, c3);
}
```

Printing

```
c1: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
c2: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
c3: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

### UPDATE

In response to the comments, I'd suggest **not** using a node-based container for efficiency. Instead, you could perhaps trade off storage by using a bitset or by optimizing for the nth percentile, so extra allocation/indirection only occurs when needed. Here's a simple example with number of particles per cell distributed uniformly on [1, 6], and extra allocation only happens when a cell's population exceeds 4:

**[Live On Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/36926a4eef62fbda)**

```
#include <boost/multi_array.hpp>
#include <boost/range/iterator_range.hpp>
template <typename T> //
struct MAMatrix : boost::multi_array<T, 2> {
    using Base = boost::multi_array<T, 2>;
    using Base::operator=;

    MAMatrix(MAMatrix const&) = default;
    MAMatrix(long n1 = 0, long n2 = 0) : Base(boost::extents[n1][n2 ? n2 : n1]) {}

    auto lists_size() const { return Base::num_elements(); }
    auto lists_begin() { return Base::origin(); }
    auto lists_end() { return lists_begin() + lists_size(); }
    auto lists() { return boost::make_iterator_range(lists_begin(), lists_end()); }

    auto begin() { return flatten(lists_begin(), lists_end()); }
    auto end() { return flatten(lists_end(), lists_end()); }
};

#include <fmt/ranges.h>
#include <boost/container/small_vector.hpp>
#include <random>
using boost::container::small_vector;

int main() {
    auto dist = bind(std::uniform_int_distribution(1, 6), std::mt19937{std::random_device{}()});

    MAMatrix<small_vector<int, 4>> cells(3, 4);
    for (int i = 0; auto& l : cells.lists())
        generate_n(std::back_inserter(l), dist(), [&] { return i++; });

    fmt::print("c1 lists:     {}\n", cells.lists());
    fmt::print("c1 flattened: {}\n", cells);
}
```

Printing outputs like

```bash
for a in {1..4}; do (set -x; ./a.out); done
+ ./a.out
c1 lists:     [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10], [11], [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17], [18, 19, 20, 21, 22], [23, 24, 25], [26], [27], [28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33], [34, 35, 36, 37], [38, 39, 40, 41]]
c1 flattened: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41]
+ ./a.out
c1 lists:     [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11], [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17], [18, 19], [20, 21, 22, 23, 24], [25, 26, 27, 28], [29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34], [35, 36, 37, 38], [39], [40], [41], [42]]
c1 flattened: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42]
+ ./a.out
c1 lists:     [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13], [14], [15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20], [21, 22, 23, 24], [25], [26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31], [32], [33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38], [39, 40, 41], [42, 43, 44]]
c1 flattened: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44]
+ ./a.out
c1 lists:     [[0], [1, 2], [3, 4, 5, 6], [7, 8], [9, 10, 11], [12, 13], [14, 15, 16, 17, 18], [19, 20, 21, 22], [23, 24, 25, 26, 27], [28, 29], [30, 31, 32, 33], [34]]
c1 flattened: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34]
```

Comment: Trivial tweak to allow non-square extents: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/45f18aef762fb7b9

Comment: Thank you for your in-depth answer and the references! However, I think it does not completely answer the question of how to iterate over a `boost::multi_array<std::list<int>>`. Both the rethink sections cover the case `boost::multi_array<int>`, but I *really* need the former, and if the elements of the `multi_array` are `std::list<int>`, then they should also support `push_back`.

Comment: I realize that giving the case of nested vectors as a comparison case probably made the impression that I only want to model a 2D array of `int` with both approaches. But I just gave that case, too, because the `flattening_iterator` I took form the linked answer worked in that case.

Comment: Yeah the reference confused me. Basically you need a double flatten (with [the same explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77396591/flattening-iterator-for-boost-multi-array-of-linked-lists?noredirect=1#comment136454481_77396591:~:text=A%20multi%2Darray%20is%20an%20abstraction%20that%20behaves%20like%20a%20container%20of%20sub%2Darrays) as before). I'd use `multi_array`'s contiguous storage for the first level again, and you end up with: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e1a0b74108c65291

Comment: Mind you, at this point I strongly believe you should go 3D array instead of using `list` anyways, removing the need for flattening in the first place: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ba4e489e96c1b939. In fact, if you generalize this you end up with `multi_array` itself

Comment: Just to illustrate that last point with a generalized N-dimensional flattening matrix: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/95e0b42e40630730 (showing 1 through 4 dimensional examples)

Comment: Thanks, your double flatten code works! Would you mind pasting it also in the answer so to have it completely here? The background behind wanting to use lists for the last level is that I want to implement a demonstration code for cell lists as described here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cell_lists

Comment: Based on that I added a [slightly modified version](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/36926a4eef62fbda) with explanation. Do consider bitsets (assuming "int" is a unique identification of particles) or even [spatial indexes[(https://beta.boost.org/doc/libs/1_82_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/spatial_indexes/boost__geometry__index__rtree.html) which ...

Comment: provide highly optimized [cell bound lookup](https://beta.boost.org/doc/libs/1_82_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/spatial_indexes/group__predicates/within_geometry_const___.html) or [k-nearest](https://beta.boost.org/doc/libs/1_82_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/spatial_indexes/group__predicates/nearest_geometry_const____std__size_t_.html). You can benchmark which is fastest for your scale/access patterns. Note: rtree is likely only faster if your access patterns are query-heavy and mutation-low

Comment: Thank you very much for the help and the additional explanations and pointers!

Comment: Just out of curiosity I did a very simple simulation - which is mostly bad because it builds the cell list/spatial index for each run - which for some tunings can be faster for cell list and some faster for rtree - but the rtree unsurprisingly considers far fewer spurious candidates. https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/241740ca3a14c83a